# Counts of unique values in Postgres GROUP BY

Tags: sql, postgresql, pandas

I have a table with schema:

```
uid | day | type
```

In `pandas`, it looks like this:

```
d=pd.DataFrame(columns=['uid','day','type'])
d.loc[0]=[1,1,'C']
d.loc[1]=[1,1,'T']
d.loc[2]=[1,1,'C']
d.loc[3]=[2,1,'T']
d.loc[4]=[1,2,'T']
```

I want to:

- `GROUP BY` `uid` and `day`.
- Get the count of unique `type` values per group.
- Return the top 3 `type` values per group.

In `pandas`, it's possible to get counts of unique values per group:

```
d.groupby(['uid','day']).type.value_counts()
```

The output (then I would filter to get the top 3 per group).

```
uid  day   
1    1    C    2
          T    1
     2    T    1
2    1    T    1
```

How would this query be done in `postgres`?

Comment: You want the count of types for each uid and day? Add sample data and expected output to your question.

Comment: Thanks, just did that. Appreciate any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure to completely understand your question, but as I can't leave a comment I'll just give it a try.

Let's say we have the table t containing these data :

```
 uid | day | type 
-----+-----+------
   1 |   1 | C
   1 |   1 | T
   1 |   1 | C
   2 |   1 | T
   1 |   2 | T
```

Then this query will return what you want :

```
  SELECT uid, day, type, count(type) 
  FROM t 
  GROUP BY uid, day, type;

 uid | day | type | type_count 
-----+-----+------+------------
   1 |   1 | C    |     2
   1 |   2 | T    |     1
   1 |   1 | T    |     1
   2 |   1 | T    |     1
```

Then you can make an ORDER BY DESC on the column type_count with a LIMIT 3 and you get your top 3.

I hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. Here's the question in simple terms: how to get frequency of comment types for each user on each day? Point is that `postgres` doesn't appear have an agg function to compute frequencies for items in a group. So, I'm wondering how this would easily be done.